# Row aggregations using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

So I want to aggregate the values of the rows of my data.table using custom functions. For instance, I know that I can sum over the rows doing something like

```
iris[,ROWSUM := rowSums(.SD),.SDcols=names(iris)[names(iris)!="Species"]]
```

and I could get the mean using rowMeans. I can even control which columns I include using .SDcols. However, lets say I want to compute the 20th percentile of the values of each row (using, for example, quantile()). Is there any way to do this that does not entail looping over the rows and setting a value per row?

Comment: BTW, if you are using `rowSums`, you don't need a group by operation for `Species`  Perhaps `as.data.table(iris)[, rowQ := matrixStats::rowQuantiles(as.matrix(.SD), probs = 0.2), .SDcols = 1:4]`

Comment: Makes sense, didn't know that package. But what if I want to apply a totally custom aggregation?